# What is the name of the time format PT00H00M00S and what languages use it?

Tags: php, regex, types, time

I'm working with excel documents using PHP scripts and cannot determine what data type/format PT00H00M00S is, and subsequently I can't find a way to work with it without using regex. I'd like to convert this into a more standard time format (00:00:00) and I can't research this on google because I don't know what "PT...S" is actually called as a date type/format.

Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an **ISO 8601 duration**.

See this brief overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Many languages have tools available to work with them, including PHP in the form of [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval).

Answer (score 1):

It's a time interval, where the `P` means period. You can use PHP's [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to parse the string.

For example (example taken from the PHP documentation):

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P2Y4DT6H8M');
echo $interval->format('%d days');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an ISO 8601 format to give the duration.

**P** stands for the period, and **T** for intervals which contain a time component, i.e. hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
"5 hours 30 minutes" --> PT5H30M
"7 minutes" --> PT7M
"2 hours" --> PT2H
```

This format is straightforward, but performing any operation over it is difficult.

In PHP, we have an inbuild function to convert it to seconds.

```
(new DateTime('@0'))->add(new DateInterval('P2DT4H30M'))->getTimestamp()
```